# Disabling Hibernate Second level cache Read Or Update for specific query

Tags: hibernate, redis, second-level-cache

I have Redis as my second level cache for Hibernate. I enabled caching for an entity based on its ID. However, I have few queries I need to run based on other attributes such as name, age etc... in which case, my current implementation is still hitting the cache, missing it, updating the entity if anything changed. Since it is caching based on ID, it is missing it. I want to ignore going to Cache if it is not requested with ID. What is the way to do it?

Let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set [CacheMode.IGNORE](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/CacheMode.html#IGNORE) using `Session.setCacheMode(CacheMode)`.

This would ignore the second level cache to read the data from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of second-level-caching:

1. Caching entities (by id, or caching natural id -> id mapping) and collections
2. Query caching

It seems you've been thinking about the first one which happens when you do `session.load(MyEntity.class, id)`. When you execute another type of query (e.g. `SELECT * FROM MyEntity WHERE age > 18`) you may use the query cache, enabled by setting `hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true` and marking the query with hint `org.hibernate.cacheable` that caches the result by the query string.